# Combine similar records with unique characteristics

Tags: sqlite

I have a list of data that looks like this:

```
|key|last  |first  |email    |degree  
|1  |Hope  |Bob    |a@1.com  |BA  
|1  |Hope  |Bob    |a@2.com  |MA  
|1  |Hope  |Bob    |a@1.com  |PhD  
|2  |Pane  |Pat    |b@1.com  |BA  
|2  |Pane  |Pat    |b@2.com  |MD
```

I need to combine this data to show multiple variants of the same field to look like this, so that there is a primary key:

```
|key  |last  |first  |email1   |email2   |degree1  |degree2  |degree3    
|1    |Hope  |Bob    |a@1.com  |a@2.com  |BA  |MA  |  PhD   
|2    |Pane  |Pat    |b@1.com  |b@2.com  |BA  |MD  |  Null
```

The columns would need to "generate" as needed. e.g., If there was only 1 record that had 19 emails, it would generate 19 email columns even if the rest only had a max of 2.

I've tried to self joins to dice up and add together later with this:

```
SELECT a.key,a.last, a. first, a.email, a.degree 
b.key, b.last, b.first, b.email, b.degree 
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b 
ON a.key = b.key and a.email=b.email and a.degree=b.degree
```

But I got stuck. It didn't join right. And that was step one. I'm asking here to see if I'm even on the right track. Shouldn't it only combine on the things that match from the the left table? It ended up duplicating the records. An inner join will eliminate records with only 1 email, or department. Just looking for a way to do this.

Kind of stuck.

Comment: Can you fix formatting?

Comment: StackOverflow uses [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) dialect.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible with plain SQL (although some Transact SQL probably would do). Instead you may create data using some imperative programming language (Java, Python, whatever you like).

Answer (score 0):

> The columns would need to "generate" as needed. e.g., If there was
>   only 1 record that had 19 emails, it would generate 19 email columns
>   even if the rest only had a max of 2.

is a problem because sql returns a fixed number of columns.

The self join example returned all the rows because the on clause matches the rows in a to the rows in b. One to one.

The  [group_concat() aggregate function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat)  might get you closer, depending on how you intend to use the result. This query:

```
select key,first,last,group_concat(email) email_list,group_concat(degree) degree_list
from table
group by key
```

Returns this result:

```
key         first       last        email_list               degree_list
----------  ----------  ----------  -----------------------  -----------
1           Bob         Hope        a@1.com,a@2.com,a@1.com  BA,MA,PhD
2           Pat         Pane        b@1.com,b@2.com          BA,MD
```